# export data from grafana querty to the excel file by python

Tags: python, excel, grafana

Need to export data from grafana dashboard - query data.My Grafana use SQLite. Say me please, can i use python script for connecting to the grafana db and take data from here? Or better to use python API request to the dashboard?

I was googling around and it looks like I can use the api to create dashboards/visuals and administer them but not sure where how to use the api to export the data.

I need in numeric value of grafana metric and exprot it in excel file

I would appreciate if you sent a some of examples of how to do this

Comment: Afaik that is not possible via the Grafana API, only using the UI. Assuming you query a database with Grafana, why not query that database directly from your python script?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How I understand the only correct way it  to connect to the Grafana database file grafana.db ind take data from here, right?

Comment: Okay I'm not exactly sure now what you want to achieve. The grafana.db file only contains Grafana data like users, dashboard jsons, etc. In your question it sounded like you want to get the data that is displayed in the dashboards (and therefore queried from some other database, e.g. MySQL).

Comment: Yes you right. We use grafana for monitoring electricity consumption, and we want to do automatic report of consumption for day, month, year. I go in my grafana ini file and see that we use SQLite3 db. CAn i connect to it and take data?

Comment: As I said, the SQLite3 database/grafana.db file stores only Grafana data, not your monitored data. There must be a data source configured, retrieving the consumption data from some other database. Find out which database that is and get your data from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaining. Now I understand in what way need to move for export monitoring data from Grafana

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.